# Changing dynamically one method of a class

Tags: python, class, methods

My question is twofold.
First, I would like to define a class having one method `scale` that behaves differently depending on the value assigned to one of its properties.
Below is my current attempt with `XXX` signling parts of the code where something is missing.

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._scaling_method = None

    def same(self, u):
        return u

    def double(self, u):
        return u * 2

    scale = same

    @property
    def scaling_method(self):
        return self._scaling_method

    @scaling_method.setter
    def scaling_method(self, value):
        if value.lower() == "double":
            self._scaling_method = "double"
            print "Scaling method set to 'double'."
            # XXX method scale should be set to double
        elif value.lower() == "same":
            self._scaling_method = "same"
            print "Scaling method set to 'same'."
            # XXX method scale should be set to same
        else:
            print "Unknown scaling method."
```

If `c` is an instance of `C`,I want to be able to do

```
c.same(3) # yields 3
c.double(3) # yields 6
c.scale(3) # yields 3 because scale defaults to same
c.scaling_method = "double"
c.scale(3) # yields 6
```

Once this is correctly set up, I would like to be able to set the `scaling_method` property with an argument and define the `scale` method accordingly in the `__init__`. For now, the only solution I see for this second part is to define each scaling method both in the core of the class and in the `__init__` section, which seems pretty awkward.

*edit*: I just noticed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15944344/1266155) which may be adapted here.

Comment: Do you want to use a different method of the *class* or of the *instance*?

Comment: *I would like to define a class having one method scale that behaves differently depending on the value assigned to one of its properties.* While this is doable - it's not exactly what I'd consider a very clean design. Does it *have* to be by assignment of a property? Or are you open for other (more Pythonic ways) that can achieve something similar?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams of the *class*.

Comment: @JonClements I open to any suggestion.  The only thing is that it should be possible to do something like `c.scaling_method` to know what is the current scaling method.

Comment: Then how come you're using `self` in the property? Or a property at all for that matter?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I want to be able to change the method of an `instance`, picking one among the method `class`. Any confusing elements in my code above is only due to my very limited knowledge of python and oriented object programming generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, it is not clear if you want to do it on a class basis or instance basis.
Here is a solution which work on the instance basis. I overload the scale method:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._scaling_method = None

    def same(self, u):
        return u

    def double(self, u):
        return u * 2

    scale = same

    @property
    def scaling_method(self):
        return self._scaling_method

    @scaling_method.setter
    def scaling_method(self, value):
        if value.lower() == "double":
            self._scaling_method = "double"
            self.scale = self.double
        elif value.lower() == "same":
            self._scaling_method = "same"
            self.scale = self.same
        else:
            print "Unknown scaling method."
```

If you want it on a class basis, replace `self.scale = ...` by
`self.__class__.scale = ...`. Note: this could be considered as hacky
because I'm really changing the class.

Then

```
sage: c = C()
sage: c.scale(3)
3
sage: c.scaling_method = "double"
sage: c.scale(3)
6
```

Note that the other objects of the class are not affected:

```
sage: cc = C()
sage: cc.scale(4)
8
```

If you want to have the same behavior on a class basis:

```
class C(object):
    _scaling_method = None

    def same(self, u):
        return u

    def double(self, u):
        return u * 2

    scale = same

    @property
    def scaling_method(self):
        return self._scaling_method

    @scaling_method.setter
    def scaling_method(self, value):
        if value.lower() == "double":
            self.__class__._scaling_method = "double"
            self.__class__.scale = self.double
        elif value.lower() == "same":
            self.__class___.scaling_method = "same"
            self.__class__.scale = self.same
        else:
            print "Unknown scaling method."
```

Then as in the previous code:

```
sage: c = C(); cc = C()
sage: c.scale(2), cc.scale(3)
(2, 3)
sage: c.scaling_method = "double"
sage: c.scale(2)
4
```

But now `cc` is affected too:

```
sage: cc.scale(3)
6
```

Comment: You are totally right. I deleted my previous comment because it was too nonsensical to serve any purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I derived from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15944344/1266155). The `print` statements could be replaced with proper error handling.

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, scaling_method="same"):
        self._list_scaling_methods = ("same", "double")
        if scaling_method in self._list_scaling_methods:
            self._scaling_method = scaling_method
        else:
            print "Unknown scaling method."
            self._scaling_method = None

    @property
    def scaling_method(self):
        return self._scaling_method

    @scaling_method.setter
    def scaling_method(self, value):
        if value in self._list_scaling_methods:
            self._scaling_method = value
        else:
            print "Unknown scaling method."

    @property
    def scale(self):
        return getattr(self, self._scaling_method)

    def same(self, u):
        return u

    def double(self, u):
        return u * 2
```